# Rails 3 update two models using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been stuck on this for about 2 weeks.  I need help in the proper way to do this.  I have two models.  Model one is Leads.  Model two is Referrals.

Leads belongs_to referrals

Referrals has_many Leads

In the Lead entry screen there is a partial that displays possible Referrals for the lead to select from.  There is an Add Referral link in the partial that brings up a modal using twitter bootstrap as the css framework.  From that I am rendering the New action of the Referral controller.

This all works up to this point.  What I want to have happen is that I can then enter a new referral, it is saved, the modal closes, and the list of referrals in the partial of the Leads edit/new view is then updated to reflect the new referral that has been added.  But at this point I now have nested form_for's.  As well as a Referral form that is working off a different controller.

I am not sure how I should approach this.  I have been searching and trying various methods for a couple of weeks now.  Do I repeat myself and completely rebuild the Referral view and controller under the Leads controller and view?  Repetitive code like that is why I switched to rails, and why I feel I'm not looking at this correctly.  There has to be a simple way around this.  I have looked at using Gems like Draper and Cell, and I've read up on using presenters.  But those seem to all be solutions for a dashboard type of view, not what I am trying to accomplish.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way i program this kind of problem.
It works for me, maybe you can adapt to your own situation.

Well, you `create` action on yout Referral Controller should respond with javascript.

```
if @referral.save
    format.js
```

This way, you will have a `create.js.erb` file whitin the views folder where you keep your referral's views.
In the `create.js.erb` you may have something similar to this:

```
$('#modal_id').hide(); // Hide the modal or if you prefer, remove from DOM.
$('#referral_list_id').chidren().delete(); // Remove the list of referrals.
$('#referral_list_id').html(
  "<%= escape_javascript(render('referrals_list')) %>"
); // Render a partial with the new content from your controller.
```

Your `form` for a new `referral` inside your modal, should be remote too:

```
<%= form_for @referral, :remote => true do %>
```

Maybe you will run into some gotchas while implementing this way, but i believe it is kinda easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ran into a few issues.  First was getting the form_for's in the correct spot (I had nested them one inside the other), the other is with the create.js.erb I found I had to move the $('#modal_id').hide() to be the last statement otherwise if it ran as the first statement in the js file the others had no affect.  Anyway thank you, this help to get me on the right track to a solution.